# MongoDB Node Driver UpdateOne Promise Parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am confused about the parameters that are passed through to the promise function of write operations.

For example, the docs for [updateOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#updateOne) say that the callback is an instance of [updateWriteOpCallback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpCallback) which has parameters `error` and `result`.

```
db.collection.('my-collection')
    .updateOne({_id: someObjectID}, {$set: someChanges}, function(err, result){
        console.log(err); //null
        console.log(result); //CommandResult
    }
```

In the above example, if the operation is successful, `err` is correctly set to null and `result` contains the result.

However, if I choose to us a promise instead of a callback:

```
db.collection.('my-collection')
    .updateOne({_id: someObjectID}, {$set: someChanges})
    .then((err, result) => {
        console.log(err); //CommandResult
        console.log(result); //undefined
    }
```

The first parameter `err` is actually giving me what should be in `result`, and `result` is undefined.  Is there an explanation for why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because that isn't how promises work. When a promise gets rejected, you are supposed to catch it with the `promise.catch()` method, not `promise.then()`.

So:

- `promise.then()` is used to get the result of the `resolve()` operation.
- `promise.catch()` is used to get the result of the `reject()` operation.

Thus your code should be:

```
db.collection.('my-collection')
    .updateOne({_id: someObjectID}, {$set: someChanges})
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```